# Django admin as internal tool

Tags: django, django-admin, project-management

I intend to use django's powerfull admin interface doubled by django admin tools to write an internal project management tool. The application would only have this backend, no frontend.

This project will not be commercial, will not go online, maximum  projected users will be arround 40.
We're a movie post production studio, we need this tool to better organize tasks and have a general overview for our projects.

Do you guys think it's safe? Can the django admin be used for this purpose?
Thank you, go easy on me as this is my first question. :)

Comment: Why not to use something existing and save the time?

Comment: don't try reinvent the wheel. The money/time spent to develop this would be better spent using an existing service such as Basecamp

Comment: basecamp is not visual effects oriented, there are other software packages such as shotgun but very expensive. Our internal workflows are not compatible with any of the document based project management suites. We have 100 files for one shot, and another 500 additional helper files that go to that shot, we work with 10 different software packages, each with it' s own file structure. Plus, this project manager will be integrated within every software. Auto save paths, auto write paths, auto versioning on lots of applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Django admin site can almost be fully customized and provides a lot of hooks to seamlessly configure and override a lot of the default behavior. It's built to be a common interface for applications to automatically integrate with and expose data management, so in practice you'll never see applications providing their own views and URL hooks to expose some kind of custom management interface.

The point where it becomes quirky to customize it is when you need to use it for something other than it's intended purpose. It's meant for managing application models and the whole admin site is structured and organized around the notion of providing very specific CRUD views for registered model instances. You'll find that, in turn, the default views prepare special contexts for the templates that are meant to be supportive for a particular assumption of how CRUD behavior should be generically provided for application models and that extending or customizing them in ways other than what's readily supported by `ModelAdmin` instances will be very time-consuming and lead to a lot of pain.

You should definitely take the time to explore the [Django admin site documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/) and understand thoroughly what it can do and plan out your application so that it goes with and not against the assumptions and capabilities of the admin site.

If your still in the position that you do need the admin site to provide highly-customized presentation and structure, then fear not. Django's [class-based generic views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/) provide an equally powerful abstraction for working with your models, without being constrained to the requirements of the admin site, and picking [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) off the shelf for presentation means you can roll out your application the way you want it just as fast.

Comment: +1 because you "stole" my thoughts and for mentioning `Bootstrap`. Many times that I found myself pushing django's admin beyond its limits, I went ahead for bootstrap and generic views.

Comment: Thanks alot. very helpfull advice. I'm starting to love stackoverflow.